# How to express this idea

Tags: grammar, phrase-request

If I found there is an error in a quote I offered in my previous email, and then l rewrote the right price in a new mail, how to express the receiver should view the price as correct, the price in the previous is wrong.

Comment: I would start with something like "I am sorry (or other similar apology phrase). but there was (I made) an error in my previous email. The correct information is as follows..."

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like

> I am sorry (or another similar apology phrase). but there was (I made) an error in my previous email. The correct information is as follows...

I would put it like:

> As for the price/quote I have offered in the previous email, please notice that $abc is wrong and $xyz is correct.